# A tool to convert email to html

Tags: email, html-email

Is there a programmatic tool that converts an email (rfc822 with mime and attachments) into html? It can be a python/perl/java library/module or a command line linux tool. I need to create a valid html (even if some parts of email aren't so valid). I don't need to check for virii and spam because the mail is assumed to be already cleared. A plus is to check for obviously dangerous things like javascripts and remote images but I can do it myself once I have a proper html.

The program is meant to be run from a script, so advice requiring human intervention is not relevant unless it can be run from Linux-based headless server, because it is meant to be run from a server script.

Yes, there is [mhonarc](http://www.mhonarc.org/) but it looks a bit obsolete and it generates many perl warnings.

I also tried python's mailparser but it looks it lacks a converter to html.

Comment: here's a list http://www.emailman.com/conversion/

Comment: I just installed `mhonarc` from its current Ubuntu package, got no warnings, and am now happily browsing an old email archive as HTML. The tool might have improved since you tried it last in 2013.

Answer (score -2):

Open the email message that you want to save.
Click "File > Save As". (If you are using en email client other than Microsoft Outlook, the actual menu options may differ slightly.)

[HTML EDITOR](http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=C938A1XuWUYjGI-i6igfg8oGIC6CBxYMBiPnNnwzAjbcBEAEgqYmtBlD4uOLiAmDlkuiD2A6gAcDtkf8DyAEBqAMBqgSHAU_Qq8-u9qyUW6DrLw4u44--GHcjgvRbg7wvMeFImNUbDirl7B8AExQhLaxMv1E7Kkv9N9H8aLS5nL9TgpYK6B4znt8xdzAgoMOXloO4OV_VDMCNLGV21Vi1JzNkTMFmMJrwX9emGisx7eG9wHTr83G1aopEE1DM3aG2chIdf6T55Tpa9jrJZIgGAYAHqJJu&num=1&cid=5GgkoJz-xb0h4weMkhvBwWnp&sig=AOD64_2EoeKG09ckyZn18wcXgOLjMpxe9w&client=ca-ehow_300x250&adurl=http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html?source=adwords&campaign=ultraedit-content&adgroup=content-html-editor&adnum=003)

Use the fields in the "Save As" dialog box to navigate to and select the folder where you want to save the file.

Type a name for the file in the "File name" text box.

Select "HTML" from the "Save as type" drop-down menu.

Click "Save". Double-click the file to open it in a browser window. Open the file in a text editor such as Notepad to view or edit the actual HTML code.

Comment: A quicker method for this in Outlook is to right click the email somewhere along the bottom edge. Needs to be directly under the html, but still within the email itself. Then select 'View Source'. It will open the html code in your default text editor.

Comment: No, I don't need interactive program. I need a script or command line program. I want to do this server-side without a user with a mouse.